# How to filter Remote Syslog messages on Red Hat?

Tags: linux, filter, redhat, rsyslog

I'm using a unified log on a server running **Red Hat 6**, receiving directed log messages from others servers and managing them with **RSyslog**. Until now, the */etc/rsyslog.conf* have this rule:

```
if $fromhost-ip startswith '172.20.' then /var/log/mylog.log
```

But I don't want to log messages that contains "kernel" and "dnat", so I want to filter all messages, enhancing the rule.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a question better suitable for [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). Having appropriately notified that this is not the right place, I'll go and break the rules by answering it anyway.

Depending a bit on the version of Red Hat you're using, you can use rsyslogd's [conditional filters](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v5-stable/configuration/filters.html) or [RainerScript](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rainerscript.html) in various ways to express a combination of several logical rules. On Red Hat 6 you could say something like this to accomplish what you want using a conditional filter:

```
if ( $fromhost-ip startswith '172.20.' and \
     $syslog-facility-text != 'kern' ) then /var/log/mylog.log
```

You can find more examples from the [Rsyslog v5 manual](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v5-stable/#manual).

Comment: I made it! That's how:
`if ( $fromhost-ip startswith '172.20.' and not $msg contains 'kernel' ) then /var/log/mylog.log`